# VBA: IMPORT data from closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel, import, copy

I didn't find explicit solution for this problem.

I want to copy all data from closed `Ws.Data` to active `CurrentWs.Data`. Do you guys have any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Just of curiosity - why don't you want to open `Ws.Data`, copy the sheets and close it again? There is a good solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with ADODB connection :

```
Sub copyFromWs()
Dim Cnx As ADODB.Connection
Dim fileToCopy As String
Dim SheetName As String, request_SQL As String
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset


fileToCopy = "C:\monClasseurBase.xls" 'here you can use something like ws.data.pathname
SheetName = "Sheet1" 'Here it's your ws.Data
Set Cnx = New ADODB.Connection

'Connection
With Cnx
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & filetocopy & _
        ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With


'Request
request_SQL= "SELECT * FROM [" & SheetName & "$]"

Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Rst = Cnx.Execute(request_SQL)

Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Rst 
'Here for you something like currentws.Data.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Rst

'Close
Cnx.Close
Set Cnx = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This link is great for copying data from a closed workbook.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm

Or, try this.

```
Sub ImportDatafromcloseworkbook()
'Update 20150707
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That code copies from an open workbook, not from a closed workbook.